# How to add theme for assets url used in box view api viewer.js

Tags: javascript, box-view-api

I would like to know how to add a theme for box view api viewer.js

```
var viewer = Crocodoc.createViewer('.viewer', { 
                                    url: '{ASSETS_URL}' 
             });
```

This works and display a plan document.

But if try adding a theme parameter such as ASSETS_URL/theme/dark or ASSETS_URL?theme=dark this doesn't work.

Can someone help in this? I need to get a theme when my document are viewed.

Answer (score 0):

With viewer.js you have to build all of the UI yourself – it gives you access to the converted document and methods for changing pages, zooming etc, but you still have to create the UI.

If you need a viewer with pre-built themes and functionality, you should use the iframe viewer i.e. http://developers.box.com/view/#post-sessions